Error loading LAS files into my R Session using lidR on MacOS (M1)
I would like to call up or load a LAS file (Laser Point file) in my R project. My code works on a Windows 10 computer but gives an error on a on a Mac Book, M1, 2020. My code looks like this:
# Install and load required packages
required_packages <- c("lidR", "sf", "terra", "future", "progressr", "entropy", "e1071", "ggplot2", "gridExtra", "moments", "dplyr")
install.packages(setdiff(required_packages, installed.packages()[, "Package"]))
lapply(required_packages, library, character.only = TRUE)

### Load LAS-File ###
las_file <- "~/Documents/Masterarbeit/Training_data/UAV_data/classified_ndom_komplett.las"
las <- readLAS(las_file)

I get this error message:
Error: Not compatible with requested type: [type=character; target=double].
The remaining packages are used for the rest of the code and are therefore listed in the code snippet. However, the same code works on a Windows 10 computer. There, I do not receive an error message and can read and process the LAS file. I have noticed that this problem also occurs on other Mac computers. This question is more about whether this problem is known and whether there are any solutions.
I have tried to install the R package lidR to read LAS files into R, but have encountered repeated error messages, especially problems with missing gfortran libraries such as libemutls_w. I have tried several approaches, including setting environment variables, installing gcc via homebrew, creating symlinks for missing libraries, trying to install older versions of gcc, and manually compiling the package from source. The problem persists.

(I don't know much about R, but the error seems like you're calling the method with the wrong arguments? It seems like there's both LidR and rLiDAR that provide a readLAS function, and LidR expects the string filename, while rLiDAR wants a system.file() object. Is it possible you have the wrong one and it's conflicting somehow? If lidR is flat-out not installed, I'd expect it to not recognize the function name at all. But again, I don't know R very well.

I solved the problem for my case as follows.
(1) Installation of gdal, proj and laszip via Homebrew in my Mac terminal
(2) Upgrade to the latest R (4.4.1) and RStudio (2024.04.2+764) version for macOS (if necessary, completely uninstall and reinstall).
As I said, it worked for me. A new installation of R and RStudio is probably not absolutely necessary.
Thank you anyway @Kaia

can you post the solution you found as an answer and then accept it? It might help somebody else who has the same issue in the future. Glad you solved it! :)
